# Increasing Dashboard Filter Option Limit

Tags: limits, dashboard, filters

Is there a way to get around the Dashboard limit of 10 options per filter? Our use case is that we have around 60 users that we'd want to be able to see the Dashboard from their perspective, and the limit is 10. From doing some reading of the release notes, it looks like contacting Salesforce.com might get us access to 50, but I was wondering if there is a better workaround that would allow an "infinite" number of options.

> "Each dashboard can have up to three filters, and each filter can have up to 10 options. By default, you can add up to 10 options defined by operator and value for each filter. Contact salesforce.com if you want to increase this limit. A maximum of 50 per filter is possible.

http://eu1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/dashboard_filters_overview.htm

**UPDATE:** We requested and received an increase to 50 options per filter, but technically that is still restricting us.

Comment: What does "*from their perspective*" mean here?
It sounds like you could use "dynamic" dashboards, which shows data based on the logged in user.

Comment: That is what we are using, the issue is that you can only have a finite amount of them.

Answer (score 1):

What we did was create another dashboard (cloned) and put the next set of '10 filtered' filters.

- It's nice to know it's possible to get that raised to 50. - I'll have that requested :-)

Comment: This is what my current thought was, but I'd hate to be the person hunting around through a bunch of dashboards trying to find the right user. Or if we organized them alphabetically, having to reset them all once a new user was added.

Comment: Use Dashboard folders.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I opened a case with SF Technical Support team in the same regard, I need to be able to filter on user and number of users is constantly growing. What I was told is that it is designed to run 50 filters without issues, more than that limit can slow down the system. Looks like you can ask them to push over their limit